# Checksum on Network drive is really slow

Tags: ftp, checksum

I want to check if a bunch of files have copied without problem to a network drive. I am not able to ssh to the network drive, but I am able to mount it using FTP.

The number of files is about 220, and the size of the files is about 300 mbytes. The network connection is relatively fast at a maximum of 10 mbyte per second.

When I mount the network drive and do something like:

```
find . -iname '*.filetype' | xargs -I {} cksum {} >> ${tmp}/filename.txt
```

It takes about 15 minutes per file to calculate the checksum.

Can I speed up this process?

Comment: How long does it currently to copy a file from the network drive to the local host, without the checksum?  Shame you can't get it via ssh; what (would seem to be) currently happening is the whole file copied locally to a temp file, then that temp file is checksummed.  How much control do you have over the remote machine?

Comment: I think copying the file would take about the same time, which is indicative for your suggestion that the file will be copied to the local drive before the checksum is calculated. That is too bad, because that way calculating a checksum is pretty useless imo, since you want the checksum of the original file. **Could somebody confirm that copying the file to the local machine is indeed what is happening?** Unfortunately I don't have any options to ssh into the network drives...

Comment: Yeah, commands can't be executed on the remote server via FTP, so any processing done on those files occurs **after** the data is transfered to your local computer.  On a technical note, I'm not sure it's stored in a temp file; I think it may just be streamed through the memory, but the effect is the same.